# Ski/Snowboard Socks

Tags: equipment, skiing, snowboarding

I am aware that when you are going skiing/snowboarding, it is important to refrain from wearing cotton. Most ski/snowboard socks that I've seen are made from merino wool. I was wondering about other textiles that can be used to produce snowboarding socks. One textile that I am curious about is hemp. Would hemp have enough wicking properties to keep you both warm and dry?

Answer (score 3):

You have already answered your own question. Anything that keeps you dry will keep you warm. There are other fibers you can try like Bamboo or synthetics if you don't like wool. I am unsure if I've ever seen a hemp sock, sounds a little scratchy to me. Cotton is just the worst because it gets so soggy. I prefer the thinnest material possible in general because boots are so well made that all i'm looking for is an ability to wick away sweat without costing me circulation.

good luck

Answer (score 3):

Hemp, Bamboo and Cotton are often used for their absorbancy rather than wicking characteristics.

Hemp and Bamboo have become popular in some applications due to their anti=-bacterial properties and they remain more 'comfortable' than cotton when damp, but they will still absorb moisture.

I recommend Merino wool socks, and my personal preference is, as ml242 said, to go as thin as possible to ensure good control.

However, for those renting boots, a thicker sock is often preferred as it improves comfort.